# undefined method permit in strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Faced with the problem.
undefined method `permit` for `nil:NilClass`

```
def update_all
  authorize Role
  @roles = current_account.roles.where(admin: false)

  @roles.each do |role|
    permissions = params[:permissions]&.[](role.id.to_s)
    role.update(permission_params(permissions))
  end

  redirect_to edit_all_roles_path, notice: 'Permissions updated!'
end
```

In the line `permissions = params[:permissions]&.[](role.id.to_s)`
filtered `permissions`. And there are times when it returns `nil`. I understand why  method `permit` undefined. But how can I avoid it?

```
def permission_params(permission_params)
  permission_params.permit(permissions: [])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want a role's permissions updated if the result of the query is nil, you can just skip the update unless the permission is present:

```
@roles.each do |role|
  permissions = params[:permissions]&.[](role.id.to_s)
  role.update(permission_params(permissions)) unless permissions.nil?
end
```

Nil-guards are not ideal, so I might take a step back and look at what why you'd ever get `nil` for permissions in the first place. Hope this helps!